# C# Sqlite and dataGridView Database

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, windows-forms-designer

There is a datagridview table in the project into which data from the sqlite database is filled. The data is entered into the database manually using the cell value changed event (like in excel). The problem is that when I run the project in visual studio. But when I publish the project and run it, when the above event is called, the error :System.NullReferenceException: The object reference does not point to an instance of the object is thrown. Apparently the problem is in this code

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
    int columnIndex = e.ColumnIndex;
    string idString = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(idString);
    if (columnIndex != 19 || columnIndex != 20)
    {
        using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection($"DataSource = E:/UPC/db; Version = 3;"))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string newValue = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Value.ToString();
            string updateQuery = "UPDATE Students SET " + columns[columnIndex] + " = @NewValue WHERE Id = " + idString + ";";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(updateQuery, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewValue", newValue);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

    }

}
```

I don't even know which line is the problem...

Comment: You probably should add logging which will tell you more about the error (even without that, I'm a little surprised you know what the error is but not the line - how are you getting this error information ... is there anything else in the error message that does give a line number or more context?). As to what would be the cause of null refs here ...  could be anything - basically any of the variables that are reference types could possibly be null (such as your strings, which are obvious candidates). So you need to find out more. Since you have a db, check the prod file location is correct.

Comment: You should debug first and you could also implement a logger. So you can find out what is the issue exactly.

Comment: It is a common issue that the published version of a C# version triggers a NullPointerException while this doesn't happen in the Visual Studio Debugger. To fix that you need to check cell values for null, row index for validity and also fix `if (columnIndex != 19 && columnIndex != 20)` by replacing && with || like this `if (columnIndex != 19 || columnIndex != 20)`. It is impossible that column index is 19 and 20 at the same time, so it makes more sense like this.